# Row-wise correlation of two columns

Tags: r

I am a R novice and would like to compute the row-wise correlation of values in two separate columns (A and B) and preferably list the associated correlation coefficients in a third column (AxB).

```
Example:
| A | B | AxB|
|:--|:--|:---|
| 1 | 2 |    |
| 2 | 3 |    | 
| 3 | 5 |    |
```

The dataset also contains missing values (NA) which should also produce NA in the correlation.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: A correlation of 2 values is always going to be NA.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly:

```
dat <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = c(2, 3, 5))

library(dplyr)

    dat %>% 
      rowwise() %>% 
      mutate(AxB = cor(A, B)) %>% 
      ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 3
      A     B   AxB
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2    NA
2     2     3    NA
3     3     5    NA
```

Since we cannot establish the correlation out of 2 values, the results will always be NA, however.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map2`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(AxB = map2_dbl(A, B, cor))
```